# Connecting CMOS digital ICs that are powered from different power sources

Tags: power-supply, digital-logic

Imagine I have 2 CMOS devices with logic gates, etc. Both use the same nominal voltage - 5v but are powered from different sources. If I will use simple regulators like 7805 on both sides, they will give slightly different output. One may give 5.05v, some other 4.97v. The grounds of these devices will be connected. This means that sending logic zero in any direction will not cause a problem, but sending logic one to a device with lower power level may cause a problem. I can put a resistor to limit the current, but would that be adequate?

[image]

Is there anything better than this resistor? What would be a good value there? Or maybe this is not a problem at all and I can simply connect the pins directly assuming that the difference of the power levels is small? What would be the difference when the problem will start to appear for our days CMOS logic gates and micro-controllers?

Comment: Will the two power sources **always** be turned on and off at the same time?

Comment: Good question...

Comment: One of the main reasons digital circuits are useful is that you get good noise immunity. These little supply variations won't matter. As long as the noise is not big enough to cross the threshold of the devices, you should be good.

Comment: I'd use a 1Kohm resistor there. Or 10Kohm, if speed is not required. You want to avoid injecting adequate current to cause ESD latchup.Usually the level of 50 milliAmps is the minimum safe level. But I did not design these gates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 100 mV difference in Vdd levels will not normally cause any problems. No current limiting resistor would be required.

However, if it's possible for the upstream device to be powered up while the downstream device is not powered (for example during start-up or shut-down) and for the upstream device to produce a "1" output during this time, then you can get upredictable behavior.

If you need to allow for this scenario, the best solution is to re-design to avoid it entirely (for example, use a tri-state buffer with the enable pin controlled by the power state of the downstream circuit). If that isn't an option, in many cases a 5 kohm or higher series resistance can minimize problems, but even then certain circuits could still misbehave.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the difference between the supply voltages is **less than the forward voltage of a silicon diode** then you can connect the gates directly without a resistor.

If the voltage difference between the supply voltages is **at any time** more than the forward voltage of a silicon diode then you need to add a resistor.

As The Photon rightly comments, it might be that one of the supplies will be "up" later than the other so then you will have the 2nd situation and you **will** need the resistor.

*Why is that so?*

I'll explain this by drawing two CMOS inverters, each having their own power supply and adding the ESD protection diodes that are present in all ICs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKNZmP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(this circuit is somewhat simplified and does not show the full ESD protection to keep it more clear)

Suppose Ropt = 0 ohms (straight connection), then when VddA is 5 V but VddB is not present yet, VddB can be pulled up via the connection between the gates.

Assume that the input of the left inverter is "0" then pmosB will be on, this will pull up the output of the left inverter, then current can flow through Ropt, through Desd3 and pull up VddB. Then the left inverter will supply power to the inverter on the right!

This should not be allowed as it can give unexpected results. To prevent any damage it would be enough to make Ropt large enough to prevent a damaging current from flowing. As long as the signals you're using aren't very high frequency (the 4000 series logic you're using isn't that fast) a 10 kohm resistor would do the job.

This effect is also explained in this [EEVBlog video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yFh7Vv0Paw&t=1s) Dave uses a microcontroller to show this but the underlying principle is the same: power a circuit through a signal input because of the ESD protection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is more than one question... power supply and logic(?).  Anyway, Not sure if you are asking about this, but...  As far as voltage differences causing an issue for interpreting a logic "high", CMOS levels are 3.5v-5v for Logic "high" so that small difference won't be an issue [This page talks about it](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/logic-signal-voltage-levels/)